# Struggling to get GPS bluetooth auto-started on boot in 10.10

Tags: 10.10

Say I want **`gpsd`** to monitor a bluetooth device, therefore replacing DEVICES line in "`/etc/defaults/gpsd`" with:

```
 DEVICES="/dev/rfcomm0"
```

Say I also have the following content in "`/etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf`":

```
rfcomm0 {
    bind yes;
    device xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx;
    channel 1;
    comment "blah";
}
```

I would have expected the `bind yes` thing to have the connection auto-start on boot-up ([source](http://gpsd.berlios.de/bt.html)), but it didn't.

Note that this works on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Do not ask why `10.10`.

Comment: Questions about Ubuntu 10.10 are off-topic, as per the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq). *"This is not the right place for: Support of versions for Ubuntu releases past [End of Life (EOL)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29)"*

Comment: Your best bet would be to upgrade to a either Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04

Comment: @ChrisWilson I wish that was my decision.

Comment: @Tshepang, Whose decision is it? If you can convince them that you're having problems getting this feature working and that you can't get support for the currently installed version, then maybe they're get you upgraded to 12.04.

Comment: @ChrisWilson I was not actually interested in discussing this, nor was I looking for any convincing/motivation, that's why I said "Do not ask why 10.10". Anyways, it would be rather risky and expensive to upgrade, and the benefits rather small... `10.10` was quite a functional release, and I am grateful that Ubuntu still make the repositories available.

Comment: @Tshepang The benefits of *not* using Ubuntu 10.10 are *huge*, because it doesn't get security updates anymore for newly discovered vulnerabilities, and therefore **is dangerous to use**. Upgrading is one way to avoid this risk; migrating to another OS is another way. But unsupported releases of any OS, including Ubuntu, should not be in production use.

Comment: @EliahKagan I am aware of the security risks. I also wish I could upgrade, but as I mentioned, it is not exactly practical at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this to "`/etc/init.d/gpsd`" in the `do_start()` function:

```
rfcomm bind rfcomm0
```

I was happy afterwards.